# How to set focus on custom input in ReactJS using useRef and react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using custom input element and want to set focus on it after initial render. Here is my custom input element: (simple though)

```
import React from 'react';
import './Input.scss';

const input = (props) => (
    <input 
        type={props.inputtype} 
        className="input" 
        placeholder={props.hint}
        style={{width: props.width}} {...props}/>
);

export default input;
```

And this is how I am using it in my functional component:

```
const SignupPopup = (props) => {

const inputEmailRef = useRef(null);
//...
useEffect(() => {
    inputEmailRef.current.focus();
}, []);

return ( 
   <Input
      inputtype="email"
      hint="Email"
      width="100%"
      id="inputemail"
      ref={inputEmailRef}
      value={email}
      required
      onBlur={emailBlurHandler}
      onChange={inputChangeHandler}
      />);
}
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

[image]

All examples and codes that I have seen work only on native `<input ref={myRef} />` element but is there any way to do it in custom input element or wrapped input element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `React.forwardRef` to pass a `ref` to native `input` in your custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Input.scss';

const input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <input 
        type={props.inputtype} 
        className="input" 
        placeholder={props.hint}
        style={{width: props.width}}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
    />
));

export default input;
```

More details:- https://en.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed the error though but unfortunately `focus` is yet not set on input element! Any idea?

Comment: if you want to set focus only on mount, you can just try to set the prop `autoFocus`.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-rain-ov0i6?file=/src/App.js:284-293

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `ref` using [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

In this way, you could access the ref of any React component in the parent.

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
     <input 
        ref={ref}
        type={props.inputtype} 
        className="input" 
        placeholder={props.hint}
        style={{width: props.width}} 
        {...props}
     />
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed the error though but unfortunately focus is yet not set on input element! Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already solved this. I will post my solution to future fellows with the same problem. There is a functional code snippet attached to the answer if you want to check how it works.

In React (tested on v17.0.2) you can use `useRef` hook to reference an specific element. In this case you will need to

1. Import `useRef`. This can be done just like this:

```js
import { useRef } from "react";
```

2. Inside of your component (before `return`), you have to add a `const` that will call the `useRef` method we just imported:

```js
const inputRef = useRef();
```

3. Then, you have to reference `inputRef` to an element:

```js
<input
    ref={inputRef}
    placeholder="Enter a value"
/>
```

4. Finally, you can do whatever you need with that element just like accesing it like this `inputRef.current`:

```js
inputRef.current.select(); // or inputRef.current.focus(); in your case
```

```js
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

const App = () => {


  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputRef.current.select();
    // you could also use inputRef.current.focus() if you only want to focus the input
  };
  
  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2> useRef select input example </h2>
      <input
        placeholder="Other input that I dont want to focus"
      />
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder="Enter a value"
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
      > 
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>  
  );

}


const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');ReactDOM.render(e(App), domContainer);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #DDD;
  background-color: #222;
  }

form {
  padding: 0 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form * {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<!-- Don't use this in production: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as very large workaround, for future fellows, i've added as sibling an empty self-closed label to the custom input component with htmlFor attribute with the same id value of the input and the ref attribute same to useRef hook call.

On a function (e.g useEffect, or some xyzHandlerFunction) i've add the label reference with .click method and this trick give the focus on the input

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import Input from './custom_component/Input.js'

function App (props) {
  const refLabeLForInput = useRef()

  const clickHandler = () => {
    refLabeLForInput.current.click()
  }

return (
    <>
        <label htmlFor='input' ref={refLabeLForInput} />
        <Input id='input'/> 
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me to focus Input</button>
    </>
)}
```